# iPhone uiswitch slow changing value

Tags: ios, uiswitch

I'm trying to build an app for iPhone, using iOS 9 and Swift 2
I pragmatically change an UISwitch value with

```
self.mySwitch.setOn(myBool, animated: false)
console("Done")
```

The problem is that the switch change is value, but about 20-30 seconds after the "Done" is appeared in the console...

The mySwitch is inside a UITableControlView with customs cells, if I put the Switch into a normal View, all works perfectly

Thanks for the help

Comment: Most likely you are running this code in a background thread. It must be done on the main thread.

Comment: I assume that you mean a UITableViewController. Is your UISwitch inside a custom cell or only inside the UITableViewController? If it is inside a cell, you might want to check, whether your are working on the correct cell, when the setOn is called.

Comment: The cell is correct, because the Switch will update, but after many seconds... No, it is the main thread, never created others threads

Comment: No, I ask sorry, I moved the code inside a callback of a http request, it could be the problem?